# Unstoppable Service

Tags: android, service

i need to implement a service that accepts few data and should continue working until user explicitly stops it. It should show a kind of notification when a day is completed, whether to continue further or not. I have coded it but while testing, i noticed that it stopped several times after few minutes. If it is made to restart again null exception occurs. Any suggestions please.

Comment: "null exception occurs", so track it down... you have the stack trace dont you?

Comment: The only way that you can do is by using `Foreground Service`

Comment: I have a question , will be thankful if i could get its answer. If i have a service that works on data passed to it, and in that case if phone is restarted or service gets killed, how can we resume same service again? Is maintaining a database the only solution to store the data ?

Comment: you are trying to restart same service which is already stopped by user. so you have to use unbindservice method on that service first before restarting. OR mention it clearly if you are restarting the service or android device.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Service to run forever untill user explicitly stops it,

- Make service as sticky service :

  ```
  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       return Service.START_STICKY;
  }
  ```
- Add Broadcast Receiver (manifest) to listen for ON_BOOT_COMPLETE event and start the service in onReceive() method.

  ```
  <application>    
      <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
  </application>
  ```

**add permission also android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED**

By these changes your service should run forever.

Comment: Any Android service or App can be stopped by Android OS. Service is not guaranteed to run for ever, as per Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Any Android Service or app can be stopped by Android OS to reclaim resources. You can only suggest it not to do that.

The most reliable way of doing it is make your Service run in [Foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) and marking is [Sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY). But even those do not guarantee it will be running all the time. A system restart will kill your service.

Comment: But i noticed that when i restart that service it returns null error because it might have lost data for which it was working! Shall i use database to maintain that data?

Comment: Yes, if the Service gets destroyed it will loose all data. It's a new object. You can use a database or SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

better start your service in separate process or go with foreground service android.foreground service is also stops in extreme low memory issues "use START_STICKY" for restart